# How to modify the hovertemplate of histogram when using ggplotly()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, hover, histogram, ggplotly

I'm having the following data table `dt.test`:

```
dt.test <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), GPNRPlan = c(100236L, 111328L, 
124213L, 127434L, 128509L, 130058L, 130224L, 130309L, 130342L, 
130392L, 130402L, 130843L, 132067L, 132597L, 133874L, 133943L, 
133950L, 135610L, 135886L, 137233L), TB.Info = c("Below TB", 
"In TB", "In TB", "In TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", 
"Below TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", 
"Over TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "In TB"), 
    EV = c(3847.65626027868, 5338.68193802084, 10300.9948652062, 
    5038.09710335868, 0, 0, 137484.47498131, 7831.27390184494, 
    164388.072187793, 407933.536699877, 150602.438125808, 100041.996984112, 
    5507.15565463884, 11504.3745586375, 248370.436164802, 64735.121047624, 
    10593.0020416499, 6417.30039359188, 17012.0465711677, 10495.4677317902
    ), EK = c(3811.92025173996, 5586.32697111958, 10585.2526883719, 
    4877.33454328664, 0, 0, 132990.852298368, 8191.60122513343, 
    164693.884494041, 407440.302209835, 154209.736782941, 90520.9528421677, 
    5606.91878115746, 11322.4688264219, 258826.81430578, 64668.573242372, 
    10465.1665234383, 6480.83212436458, 17031.1646456238, 10590.414631028
    ), pBu = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I'm plotting a histogram for the column `EK` referenced by the different `pBu` values:

```
options(scipen = 999)
col <- c("#00943c", "#006551", "#2f52a0", "#fdc300")


EK2018 <- (dt.test %>% dplyr::mutate(pBu = as.factor(pBu)) %>%
           ggplot(aes(x = EK)) +
           geom_histogram(aes(color = pBu, binwidth = 0.3), fill = "transparent", alpha = 0.7, position = "dodge") + 
           ylab("Counts") +
           scale_color_manual(values = col) +
           theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                 plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
                 legend.title = element_blank(), 
                 legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour ="black"),
                 legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), legend.box.margin = margin(t = 1, l = 1))
           
           ) %>%
           ggplotly()%>% 
           layout(annotations = list(x = 0.45 , y = 1.01, text = "<b>2018", showarrow = FALSE, xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper'))
```

The histogram plot looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to change the `hovertemplate` a little bit. I want to delete `pBu` and `binwidth` in the hovertemplate and make the title in hovertemplate bold.
I thought this would work when replacing two commands (`geom_histogram` and `ggplotly`) by:

```
geom_histogram(aes(color = pBu, binwidth = 0.3, 
text = paste("<b>Counts: </b>", count, "<br>", "<b>EK: </b>", EK)), fill = "transparent", 
alpha = 0.7, position = "dodge") +
```

and

```
ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
 geom_histogram(
   aes(color = pBu, binwidth = 0.3, 
       text = paste("<b>Counts: </b>", ..count.., "<br>", "<b>EK: </b>", dt.test$EK)), fill = "transparent", 
   alpha = 0.7, position = "dodge")
```

and `ggplotly(tooltip = "text")`.

Comment: OH NOOOO! After my lunch break, I'm getting an error message (but it worked before lunch).  ``stat_bin() using bins = 30 Pick better value with binwidth.
ERROR: Elements must equal the number of rows or 1``. What happend? I don't know why?